# Arcpy buff does not provide the output attribute "Shape_Area"

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, buffer

I made a loop to buffer several times a certain network using arcpy. What I noticed is that when I run the code, the output files do not have the attribute fields "Shape_Area" and "Shape_Length" that I get if I perform it directly via ArcMap with the geoprocessing tool "Buffer". Still, the area is shown on the map (therefore its Shape_Area and Shape_Length cannot be zero). Is there an easy way to solve this problem, since I need the "Shape_Area" parameter to work with? My buffer code is simply:

```
#Enter the name of the fields I want to use to buffer (they exist in "network")
Buffers = ['Name1','Name1','Name1','Name1','Name1']

env.workspace = "C:\Mydirectory"

# Enter the network to be buffered. It contains the fields listed in "Buffers"
network = "FileinMyDirectory.shp"

out = "C:\Anotherdirectory.gdb"
for buff in Buffers: 
       arcpy.Buffer_analysis(network, os.path.join(out,buff), buff,)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use code block to clarify your question.

Comment: There seems to be some stuff missing in the code you posted. What is *Buffers*?  Also, you keep buffering the exact same file (*network*) each time. Normally it should create *Shape_Area* and *Shape_Length*.

Comment: I modified my question adding what you suggested me, indeed there was a part of the code missing. And yes, I am buffering the same network several times

Comment: shapearea and shapeperimiter are automatically appended to the feature class when they are in a geodatabase. You can follow @BritishSteel for outputting to a geodatabase. If you need to use a shapefile, then you can run the Add Geometry Attributes tool with your outputs. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that would achieve it:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Test\Data_Points"
Buffers = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
out = r'D:\Test\data.gdb'

for buff in Buffers:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(buff, os.path.join(out,buff[:-4] + '_buffer'), '20 kilometers')

print 'done'
```

This script takes all shapefiles from directory, buffers them, and the saves them into a geodatabase. Note that I strip the ending (*.shp*) of the input shapefile and that I add *_buffer* to the output. Both *Shape_Area* and *Shape_Length* are created.

You can see input and output here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, according to what I understood the problem was that I was not performing the geoprocessing inside a geodatabase. Now I set everything in it and it works.